# Swipe Back support in Android Studio

Tags: xcode, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for **swipe back support in Android studio like Xcode**. Does anyone know if any plugin or hack available in android studio for that?

I tried to apply with the the back functionality on mouse gesture but that doesn't work well. and its cumbersome to work with that. Its not that easy as it is in Xcode.

Comment: I also need the function !!